# Split Word into sentence using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have a column called `Test` for saving the char eg.

```
A:Hi B:13/06/2022 C:Peter
```

How to split the data of `Test` column to look like this:

| test |
| --- |
| A:Hi C:Peter B:13/06/2022 |

I want to try adding a newline to the B data using `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` but how do I split the B data in the `test` column and then add a newline using `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`. Thanks

Comment: tag your RDBMS for clarity

Comment: Also, Explain what you are trying to achieve. Why only B needs to in separate row ?

Comment: Hi all , thank for your reply.B is the date and then A and C is the char, so i want to spilt the char and date in different location for SSRS report.

Comment: @VB.netDeveloper  Tag correct RDBMS as Venkataraman Suggested

Comment: select test from table , the test is include "A:Hi B:13/06/2022 C:Peter"

Comment: @VB.netDeveloper - Tagging RDBMS Means which database you are using and version of it

Comment: If you read the description of the SQL tag, it recommends very strongly that you add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because syntax and functionality varies widely between them. Failing to add that tag wastes both your time and ours, because it delays your getting an answer, and it wastes the time of anyone who answers the question only to find that it won't work for your DBMS. Please [edit] your question to add that tag. If you don't know that DBMS you're using, step away from the keyboard until you figure it out.

Comment: MS Server and version of v17.3. thank so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server you can use string_split() to extract the B. Assuming that you have space in between.

```
declare @test varchar(100) =  'A:Hi B:13/06/2022 C:Peter'
select * from string_split(@test,' ')
where [value] like 'B%'
```